# Estou com duvida sobre o window.location.href na hora de inserir um texto da url

Tags: javascript, html

O código tinha o objetivo de copiar a url da página através de um botão e inserir o texto da url no input text, mas o texto só está aparecendo quando aperta no botão para copiar, coisa que eu não queria, o que eu fiz de errado?

**HTML**

```
<div>
        <input type="text" name="" id="kwUrl" value="" readonly>
        <button onclick="copiar()" id="kwTexto">Copiar</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function copiar() {

        var url = window.location.href;
        document.getElementById('kwUrl').value = url 

        if (navigator.clipboard.writeText(url)) {
            document.getElementById('kwTexto').textContent = 'Copiado'
        };

        setInterval( function() {
            document.getElementById('kwTexto').textContent = 'Copiar'
        }, 2500
        );

        console.log(url);
    }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Porque você esta definindo o valor do input somente quando executa a função de copiar e a função é executada apenas quando aperta o botão.

Crie uma função posterior e execute-a para fazer essa tarefa de definir o valor no input:

```
   function copiar() {
        let url = document.getElementById("kwUrl");
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(url.value);
        document.getElementById('kwTexto').textContent = 'Copiado'

        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('kwTexto').textContent = 'Copiar'
        }, 2500)
    }

    // Função de definir valor da url no input
    function definirUrl() {
        let url = window.location.href;
        document.getElementById('kwUrl').value = url 
    }

    definirUrl()  // Executa a função
```

Comment: Valeu mesmo, tava a tempos tentando resolver